# Short story: boy who speaks a dead language

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story some years back about a boy who was apparently born speaking a language nobody had heard before. Later on in his life some linguists came along and identified it as a language that had died out completely shortly before and no longer had any living speakers--other than this child. Throughout his life he was either unable or unwilling to learn any other language. I seem to recall his (perfectly normal) sister grew up and studied neuroscience or linguistics or something in order to try to understand him better.

I think it might've been in one of Gardner Dozois' anthologies, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps “Dead Languages” from the short story collection *[Rise](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1936747316)* by L. Annette Binder?

From a [review](http://www.iowareview.org/blog/l-annette-binders-rise):

> In “Dead Languages,” two parents are baffled by their young son, who
>   speaks dead languages as the ancients must have spoken them, with
>   tones. More than once, Binder compares the boy’s speech to a song,
>   giving it the power of hymn and twinning it to the Biblical stories
>   that appear in other stories in the book. The mother says of her son
>   that “she’d known him always and that he’d always be a stranger.”

And [another](http://ofblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/l-annette-binder-rise.html):

> Some stories, such as “Dead Languages,” strike at the hearts of
>   parents or would-be parents who have ever worried that their child
>   might become “lost” to them:
>
> > She hadn’t put down the grocery bags when her boy finally began to talk.
> >         She  hadn’t even closed the door.  He stood there sure as the
> >         pope and pointed at her with sticky fingers.  *Apo*, her little Nicholas
> >         said.  He looked at the ceiling, and his eyes were shut.  *Apo tou nun
> >         epi ton hapanta.*  It sounded like a song.  It sounded like the martial
> >         arts movies Gary liked to watch.  She dropped her bags at the sound. 
> >         she let them fall to the kitchen tiles, and the eggs broke and seeped
> >         through the paper. (p. 73)
>
> Here, instead of a toddler being walled away due to autism or
>   deaf-muteness, he speaks in a mixture of Attic Greek, Etruscan,
>   Ligurian and other languages long lost in antiquity.  The heartache it
>   causes Nicholas’ parents is real, but the deliver fashion, being so
>   fantastical, prevents it from being just another tale of parents struggling to understand their special child.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like "[The Lost Language](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43971)" by David H. Keller (1934), available on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v08n09_1934-01_bogof39-El_PM/page/n95/mode/2up). In it, a boy creates his own written, and even spoken, language while rejecting all attempts to have him learn his parents’ tongue.

> There was nothing wrong with the boy’s body.
> But he would not talk.
> That is the way they put it. He would not talk.
>
> There did not seem to be much mental deficiency. He learned to take
> care of himself, to adjust himself to his environment, to dress, feed,
> and amuse himself. He was really a bright, adorable, loving child.
> Accepting life as he found it, he lived in the home and with his
> family without in any way being a burden. At five years he was a
> little man, but he did not talk.

The family convenes fifty linguists to hear his spoken language when he did decide to speak, and only one found anything recognizable. This man refers to a nearly extinct dialect of Welsh, now spoken by just one person, Granny Lanarch. This intrigues the father, who says,

> "My family came from that town in 1765 ... so we certainly were Welsh
> at that time." "And it may be a case of inherited memory," added the
> daughter.

They travel to Wales, but find that Granny died two years earlier. The boy's sister determines to remain with her brother for the rest of her life, learning his language.

> "You cannot do that," whispered her father gently, almost with a
> caress in his tone. "You cannot do that, Anna. It would mean a life of
> sacrifice, a life of solitary devotion. You could not do anything
> else. Why should you sacrifice everything for him?" She simply held
> her brother the tighter, as she replied: "Because I love him."

Comment: If you think that this is the correct answer, please be so good as to check the arrow on the left side.

Comment: OP was last seen the day they asked this question 5 years ago...you may never get that green checkmark, sadly!

Comment: Probably not, but nothing ventured, nothing gained! I discovered this old question while researching a topic that will be posted shortly, so I didn't spend a lot of time on it.